# How can I create typesafe higher-order Redux action creators?

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm following the patterns shown in [Improved Redux type safety with TypeScript 2.8](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/improved-redux-type-safety-with-typescript-2-8-2c11a8062575), but I'd like to add a twist. Some of my actions are reusable in different contexts but need a bit of extra identifying information to sort them out in the reducers.

I thought I could solve this and keep my code short by adding some higher-order action creator modifiers. These would take in an existing action creator and return a new action creator that would append some information to the `meta` key of my Flux Standard Actions.

```
// Removed `payload` and `error` for this reproduction
interface FluxStandardAction<T extends string, Meta> {
    type: T;
    meta?: Meta;
}

// Our basic actions

enum ActionType {
    One = "one",
    Two = "two",
}

interface Action1 {
    type: ActionType.One;
}

interface Action2 {
    type: ActionType.Two;
}

type Action = Action1 | Action2;

function action1(): Action1 {
    return { type: ActionType.One }
}

function action2(): Action2 {
    return { type: ActionType.Two }
}

// Higher order action modifiers that augment the meta

interface MetaAlpha {
    meta: {
        alpha: string;
    }
}

function addMetaAlpha<T extends string, M extends {}, A extends FluxStandardAction<T, M>>(action: () => A, alpha: string) {
    return function (): A & MetaAlpha {
        let { type, meta } = action();
        return { type, meta }; // Error here
    }
}
```

This produces the error:

```
Type '{ type: T; meta: M; }' is not assignable to type 'A & MetaAlpha'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'type' does not exist in type 'A & MetaAlpha'. Did you mean to write 'type'?
```

While I'll appreciate understanding this error message better, my question is really about what techniques are appropriate for building higher-order action creators.

Is the `meta` key an appropriate way to implement higher-order action creators? If so, how could I implement `addMetaAlpha` in a fashion the compiler is happy with? What would a typesafe reducer that handles these augmented actions look like?

Comment: please, have a look at  [redux-fluent](https://github.com/Code-Y/redux-fluent)  for a typesafe developer experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, but the cause is that you are trying to assign an object literal where a generic type is expected, `A extends FluxStandardAction`, but that could mean in addition to `type` and `meta`, `A` could have other members, so the compiler can't really check that the object literal conforms to the shape of `A`. The following assignment would be valid in the function you wrote because the properties are known and thus it can be checked:

```
let result : FluxStandardAction<T, M> = { type: type, meta };
```

If you want to return an object with all the original properties, and the new `meta` property you could use `Object.assign` as that will return an intersection type of the type parameters.

```
function addMetaAlpha<A extends FluxStandardAction<string, any>>(action: () => A, alpha: string) {
    return function (): A & MetaAlpha {
        let act = action();
        return Object.assign(act, {
            meta: {
                alpha
            }
        })
    }
}

var metaAct1 = addMetaAlpha(action1, "DD"); // () => Action1 & MetaAlpha
```

Also I would not make `meta` optional, since if the action is augmented the property  will exist, I would change the constraint of the function (although you should see how this interacts with the rest of your code base):

```
function addMetaAlpha<A extends { type: string }>(action: () => A, alpha: string) {
    return function (): A & MetaAlpha {
        let act = action();
        return Object.assign(act, {
            meta: {
                alpha
            }
        })
    }
}

var metaAct1 = addMetaAlpha(action1, "DD"); // () => Action1 & MetaAlpha
var metaAct2 : () => FluxStandardAction<'one', { alpha: string }> =  metaAct1; // Is is assignable to the interface if we need it to be;
```

As to whether this is a standard way of doing HOC actions, I can't speak to that, but it does seem live a valid way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

After using the [provided solution for my action creators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831223/155423), I went in a slightly different direction for the reducers.

Instead of trying to completely encode the changing types of the action in the higher-order reducers, I use type guards to test if the action is "secretly" carrying one of the pieces of meta information. Based on that, I can call the underlying reducer or not.

```
// Basic actions

// Removed payload and error for this demonstration
interface FluxStandardAction<T extends string, Meta = undefined> {
    type: T;
    meta?: Meta;
}

enum ActionType {
    One = "one",
    Two = "two",
}

const action1 = () => ({ type: ActionType.One });
const action2 = () => ({ type: ActionType.Two });

type Action =
    | ReturnType<typeof action1>
    | ReturnType<typeof action2>
    ;

// Higher order action modifiers that augment the action's meta properties

interface WithGreekLetter {
    meta: {
        greek: string;
    }
}

const withGreekLetter = <T extends string, M extends {}, A extends FluxStandardAction<T, M>>(action: () => A, greek: string) =>
    (): A & WithGreekLetter => {
        let act = action();
        let meta = Object.assign({}, act.meta, { greek });
        return Object.assign(act, { meta });
    }

const isWithGreekLetter = (a: any): a is WithGreekLetter =>
    a['meta'] && a['meta']['greek'];

// A basic reusable reducer

type State = number;
const initialState: State = 0;

function plainReducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.One:
            return state + 1;
        case ActionType.Two:
            return state + 2;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// The higher-order reducer

const forGreekLetter = <S, A>(reducer: (state: S, action: A) => S, greek: string) =>
    (state: S, action: A) =>
        isWithGreekLetter(action) && action.meta.greek === greek ? reducer(state, action) : state;

// Build the concrete action creator and reducer instances

const ALPHA = 'alpha';
const BETA = 'beta';

let oneA = withGreekLetter(action1, ALPHA);
let oneB = withGreekLetter(action1, BETA);
let twoA = withGreekLetter(action2, ALPHA);
let twoB = withGreekLetter(action2, BETA);

let reducerAlphaNoInitial = forGreekLetter(plainReducer, ALPHA);
let reducerA = (state = initialState, action: Action) => reducerAlphaNoInitial(state, action);

let reducerBetaNoInitial = forGreekLetter(plainReducer, BETA);
let reducerB = (state = initialState, action: Action) => reducerBetaNoInitial(state, action);

// Exercise the action creators and reducers

let actions = [oneB(), oneA(), twoB(), twoA(), twoB()];

let stateA: State | undefined = undefined;
let stateB: State | undefined = undefined;

for (const action of actions) {
    stateA = reducerA(stateA, action);
    stateB = reducerB(stateB, action);
}

console.log({ stateA, stateB });
// {stateA: 3, stateB: 5}
```

I also experimented with trying to leverage the type system more completely, but I found that I needed to add *other* type guards to go from a generic `FluxStandardAction` to my specific action anyway. Since I had to have type guards for these, I felt the other path was simpler.

Here's the higher-order reducer that applies a type guard to the action, in case you are interested in following that path more.

```
const isAction = (a: any): a is Action =>
    Object.values(ActionType).includes(a['type']);

export const onlySpecificAction = <S, A1, A2>(reducer: (s: S, a: A1) => S, isA: IsA<A1>) =>
    (state: S, action: A2) =>
        isA(action) ? reducer(state, action) : state;
```